# Mosquitto PHP runs on Terminal but does not run in Browser Error 500

Tags: php, apache, mosquitto, libmosquitto

I'm facing a problem developing a `Mosquitto` client in php. When I execute my test code through the `Terminal` on `Ubuntu` the code works very well like this:

> root@ip-*********:/var/www/html/pairing/mqtt# php pub.php Mesage
>   published Disconnected cleanly
>   root@ip-***********:/var/www/html/pairing/mqtt#

But when I run this the same code on Browser every time I get the `HTTP ERROR 500`.

Anyone know what can be this problem? I just ajust the permissions through `chmod` but it does not work yet.

Here is the code:

```
<?php

$client = new Mosquitto\Client(); $client->onConnect('connect'); $client->onDisconnect('disconnect'); $client->onPublish('publish'); $client->connect("test.mosquitto.org", 1883, 5);

while (true) {
        try{
                $client->loop();
                $mid = $client->publish('/mqtt', "Hello from PHP");
                $client->loop();
        }catch(Mosquitto\Exception $e){
                return;
        }
        sleep(2); }

$client->disconnect(); unset($client);

function connect($r) {
        echo "I got code {$r}\n"; }

function publish() {
        global $client;
        echo "Mesage published\n";
        $client->disconnect(); }

function disconnect() {
        echo "Disconnected cleanly\n"; }

?>
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you are using Apache as web server, if so check whether mosquitto module is enabled using  else properly set enable it in /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini